# Steam Shortcuts with no Images

Tags: steam

Having created a series of shortcuts through the method of

```
properties --> general --> create desktop shortcut
```

I found that some, which I know have icons from installing it on a previous computer, do not appears to have any images anymore.  Does anyone know how to fix this.  An image of an example is [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gif0yxh4e1fggjn/Image.png).

Is there anyway to fix this? This problem keeps on catching my eyes and it makes me extremely annoyed.

Comment: This is arguably a per-game problem rather than a Steam problem. The developers are supposed to include icons of certain sizes for the library, store, desktop shortcut, etc. Some developers forget to include a desktop shortcut icon, so your desktop shortcut ends up with the generic file icon. You can find several strategies for fixing this discussed [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/220780/discussions/0/846954921844888033/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a desktop for Q.U.B.E. And it also shows just a blank icon.

To change the icon right click the shortcut and select proeperties. On the Webdocument Tab you have a button to change the icon.
On the dialog that opens when you click the button locate the .exe of the game and choose an icon, if more than one are available.
(For Q.U.B.E. you find the .exe in \steam\SteamApps\common\QUBE\Binaries\Win64\QUBE.exe)

I don't think there is a method to fix the icon for shortcuts in one go.

Comment: I've found a great way of finding icons - Google image search for the name of the game, click on search tools and set size to icon.  For the 12 games I've tested I've found an amazing icon for each.  I'm now even improving my current icons!